# UIDatePicker in PopoverView in iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, uidatepicker, uipopovercontroller, uiactionsheet

I have an iPad specific application running iOS 3.2.2 which displays a settings view in a ui popover.  This all renders great, but now I'm trying to get a date picker to render inside the view and not sure what the best approach is for displaying it.

Right now it has a button which toggles visibility of the date picker within the modal, but that seems very clumsy for managing dismissal compared to the normal approach of an action sheet.

I haven't been able to find a 'best practice' for this situation and was wondering if anyone's run into this before and could offer some suggestions or guidance.

Thanks!

Comment: Please check my answer it may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341835/uidatepicker-in-uipopover/7343106#7343106

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pls check the solution provided in the link .. might help you .
1. Create the UIDatePicker programmatically (don’t use the IB)
2. add it to the view after the popup is shown

http://omegadelta.net/2010/06/04/ipad-simulator-crashes-if-a-uidatepicker-is-in-a-uipopovercontroller/

Answer (score 0):

Note the answer here indicating that the UIPickerView must be the root view of your controller when presented in a popover. It sounds like you may be attempting to place the date picker as one of several views inside the popover. If so, you'll encounter the problem described here.

[trying to fix this error: Could not find mapped image UIPickerViewFrameLeft-162-Popover.png](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229944/trying-to-fix-this-error-could-not-find-mapped-image-uipickerviewframeleft-162/5608763#5608763)