# UIDatePicker in UIPopover

Tags: ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller, uidatepicker

I have searched the entire internet (maybe I am exaggerating a little) for a tutorial on how to put a DatePicker into a UIPopover and display that in an iPad application. I have tried creating a viewcontroller, placing the datepicker in the view controller and then:

`self.popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:sa];`

(sa is the name of the viewcontroller i created), but this doesn't work, and the app crashes.  Can anyone help?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post the code that isn't working. In other words, what have you tried?

Comment: And post what does the console say when the app crashes

Comment: "unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x583b2d0"

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Try with below code. It will work fine:

**Objective-C**

```
- (IBAction)showDatePicker:(UIButton *)sender {
    UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];//Date picker
    datePicker.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 216);
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime;
    [datePicker setMinuteInterval:5];
    [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(dateChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];//need to implement this method in same class


    UIView *popoverView = [[UIView alloc] init];   //view
    popoverView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [popoverView addSubview:datePicker];
    // here you can add tool bar with done and cancel buttons if required

    UIViewController *popoverViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    popoverViewController.view = datePicker;
    popoverViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 216);
    popoverViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
    popoverViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 216);
    popoverViewController.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = sender; // source button
    popoverViewController.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = sender.bounds; // source button bounds
    //popoverViewController.popoverPresentationController.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:popoverViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
- (void)dateChanged:(UIDatePicker *)datePicker {
    NSLog(@"DATE :: %@", datePicker.date);
}
```

**Swift 4.2**

```
 @IBAction func showDatePicker(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let datePicker = UIDatePicker()//Date picker
    let datePickerSize = CGSize(width: 320, height: 216) //Date picker size
    datePicker.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: datePickerSize.width, height: datePickerSize.height)
    datePicker.datePickerMode = .dateAndTime
    datePicker.minuteInterval = 5
    datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dateChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)

    let popoverView = UIView()
    popoverView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    popoverView.addSubview(datePicker)
    // here you can add tool bar with done and cancel buttons if required

    let popoverViewController = UIViewController()
    popoverViewController.view = popoverView
    popoverViewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: datePickerSize.width, height: datePickerSize.height)
    popoverViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
    popoverViewController.preferredContentSize = datePickerSize
    popoverViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sender // source button
    popoverViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = sender.bounds // source button bounds
    popoverViewController.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self // to handle popover delegate methods 
    self.present(popoverViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
    @objc func dateChanged(_ datePicker: UIDatePicker) {
        print("DATE :: \(datePicker.date)")
    }
```

**Same code will work iPhone also if you implement below delegate respective in view controller**

```
extension YourViewController : UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {
    func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
        // Force popover style
        return UIModalPresentationStyle.none
    }
}
```

Comment: in result method you can get date using datepicker.date

Comment: Sorry for the noob question, but how do you set up the "result" method without a delegate method? Till now, I have only created UIPopovers from existing viewcontrollers, so I set up a delegate method to pass the data. But how would I extract the data using the selector(Result) method? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Prajoth you wouldn't need to set a delegate for the date picker. If you look at the line call with [datePicker addTarget...]; the result is IBAction that view controller itself has.

Comment: @JugalKBalara check my updated code working properly for iOS8

Comment: This is great, Narayana.  Just tested in Xcode 9 on the iPad.

Answer (score 3):

Now since you have tagged **iPhone** It can clearly be assumed that you are trying to use `UIPopoverController` in `iPhone` But `UIPopoverController` is available only for `iPad`. So it is resulting in a crash since iPhone doesn't recognize that controller.

Comment: OP originally tagged iPhone, however his question states iPad, and has accepted an answer that (as you mention) would only work on an iPad. I have re-tagged this question as iPad to avoid further confusion

Comment: For further reading on "`UIPopoverController` is available only for `iPad`": http://marksands.github.io/2014/05/27/how-apple-cheats.html