# Displaying a UIDatePicker inside of a UIPopover

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, datepicker, uipopovercontroller

I'm using the following code to display a `UIDatePicker` within a `UIPopover` that is displayed when a user clicks a `UIButton`.

The problem is, it is being displayed in an awkward position and I want to add a `UIToolBar` above the `datePicker` where there is extra space.  This will have `cancel` and `done` button.  How can I accomplish this?  The button that it is displayed from is the `Date of Birth` one.

```
- (IBAction)dateOfBirthButtonPressed:(id)sender{
    UIViewController* popoverContent = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

    UIView *popoverView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    popoverView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    UIDatePicker *datePicker=[[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
    datePicker.frame=CGRectMake(0,44,320, 216);
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime;
    [datePicker setMinuteInterval:5];
    [datePicker setTag:10];
//    [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(dateChanged) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [popoverView addSubview:datePicker];

    popoverContent.view = popoverView;
    UIPopoverController *popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverContent];
    popoverController.delegate=self;
    [popoverContent release];

    [popoverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 264) animated:NO];
    [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:self.dateOfBirthButton.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please check my answer it may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341835/uidatepicker-in-uipopover/7343106#7343106

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is there a reason you couldn't just use a `UIToolbar`?

```
UIToolbar* toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 44.0)];
UIBarButtonItem* cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel
                                                                              target: self
                                                                              action: @selector(cancel)];
UIBarButtonItem* space = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                                                                       target: nil
                                                                       action: nil];
UIBarButtonItem* doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItemDone
                                                                            target: self
                                                                            action: @selector(done)];

NSMutableArray* toolbarItems = [NSMutableArray array];
[toolbarItems addObject:cancelButton];
[toolbarItems addObject:space];
[toolbarItems addObject:doneButton];
[cancelButton release];
[doneButton release];
[space release];
toolbar.items = toolbarItems;
```

Then just add the toolbar to your view.  Make sure to size it correctly and implement the `done` and `cancel` selectors.

Answer (score 0):

```
[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:self.dateOfBirthButton.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Use sender in place of self.view

```
[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:((UIButton *)sender).bounds inView:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```