# datepicker in iphone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

I need to popup the Date Picker In my application when I click On the Text Field and I done It Nicely But Issue is After Selecting the Date Date picker Will goes away From Screen and when I click on Text Field it comes Back I know its simple Yet I need help thanks in advance.

Comment: what exactly you want with the date picker

Comment: first i want to get the date from date picker and after doing it datepicker will automaticallay goes away

Comment: Put a tool bar exactly above the Date Picker and on that barbutton of toolbar add [picker setHidden: YES] and show the toolbar when u are showing the Picker.

Comment: Mr rami check this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440256/displaying-a-uidatepicker-inside-of-a-uipopover

Comment: @purva:- I done it and it works well but datepicker dont come back when I click on TextField again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
   BOOL availability ;
   availability = NO;
```

put in method where you call method to display DatePicker

```
if(availability)
{
    picker.hidden =YES;
    availability=NO;
}
else
{
    picker.hidden =NO;
    availability=YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this :- this is UITextField delgete

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{

 picker.hidden =YES; // if You want

}

-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{

        [textField resignFirstResponder];

picker.hidden =NO;// if You want

}
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
yourTextField.inputView = yourPicker;
yourPicker.delegate = self; //(you need to declare your class will implement <UIPickerViewDelegate>
```

and on

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    //change your yourTextField.text here
```