# View come up on the keyboard window. How to solve it

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I have list of the text filed in vertically. And all these are in one `UIViewController` and I am adding this `UIViewController's` View in my another class.

When I clicked on the text filed keyboard appears. And that scroll view comes on the keyboard window. How can i solve this. I am beginner and no idea about this problem.

Also when I open the UIPopover with date picker. And when I scroll the date picker for selecting the date the `UIPopoverController` also change in their layout.

Also I have attached the some screen shoot for better understanding of issue.

[image]
[image]
[image]

**Got Answer**

Thanks for your help. Solved my issue. In my demo code i have change some property of the UIView's Layer. For setting border, cornerRadius.

One More property i have set is "[self.view.layer setClipsToBounds:YES];". I don't know what is wrong in this but when i remove that line code just work fine.

But this property work fine with UIImageView.

Comment: Normal i have one UIViewController with IBOutlets and View. And Simple add UIViewController view in my another ViewController as subview.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341835/uidatepicker-in-uipopover

Comment: I have upload sample code at below location Please take look for more details.

http://files.myopera.com/minesh1/Demo_Source/viewdisorder.zip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just comment below line from PaymentView.m file `- (void)viewDidLoad` method

```
[InnerView setClipsToBounds:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear with text,put some code.
However seeing the images in red block a suggestion could be reduce the y-axis of the y axis of your view which is coming over the keyboard.