# Date and Time in UIActionsheet Picker

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiactionsheet, actionsheetpicker

Hi I have a requirement where I need to show date and time in uiactionsheet on an iPad only app.

My google /sof search lead me to the following resource  https://github.com/TimCinel/ActionSheetPicker

```
ActionSheetDatePicker *actionSheetPicker = [[ActionSheetDatePicker alloc] initWithTitle:@"" datePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime selectedDate:[NSDate date] target:self action:@selector(onDateSelected:element:) origin:sender];
actionSheetPicker.hideCancel = YES;
[actionSheetPicker showActionSheetPicker];
```

It works great except for the life of me I can't find where I can set the minimum , maximum date and intervals.
Please if any one has used this could help that be great. Thank you

Comment: better use UIDatePicker and ActionSheet yourself, rather than following any such library.

Answer (score 1):

```
 UIActionSheet *menu = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Date Picker" 
                                                  delegate:self
                                         cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                    destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                         otherButtonTitles:nil];

    // Add the picker
    UIDatePicker *pickerView = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
    pickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime;
    [menu addSubview:pickerView];
    [menu showInView:self.view];    
    [menu setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0,320, 300)];

    CGRect pickerRect = pickerView.bounds;
    pickerRect.origin.y = -100;
    pickerView.bounds = pickerRect;
```

Above code is useful for add `UIDatePicker` to `UIActionSheet`. In above code you can display Date and time by using `UIDatePicker`.

Comment: Thanks, but it only displays 1 line of the dates, how do I increase the size of the picker to show the normal size date picker? I am using this code in iPad not iPhone

Comment: @iPatel How to add action events using UIActionSheet on Done button click

Comment: @jalakpatel - you can use delegate method of UIActionSheet for that.

Answer (score 1):

Here i am using Actionsheet + UIDatePicker for iPhone/IPod, BUT for iPAD using POPOVERCONTROLLER + UIDATEPICKER.

```
- (IBAction)showAction:(id)sender
{

aac = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                                 delegate:self
                                        cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                   destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                        otherButtonTitles:nil];

self.dtPicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 44.0, 0.0, 0.0)];


UIToolbar *pickerDateToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
pickerDateToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
[pickerDateToolbar sizeToFit];

NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


UIBarButtonItem *cancelBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(DatePickerCancelClick:)];
[barItems addObject:cancelBtn];

UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(DatePickerDoneClick:)];

[barItems addObject:doneBtn];


[pickerDateToolbar setItems:barItems animated:NO];

if (IS_IPHONE) {

    [aac addSubview:pickerDateToolbar];
    [aac addSubview:dtPicker];
    [self.view addSubview:aac];
}
else {
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];

    [view addSubview:pickerDateToolbar];
    [view addSubview:dtPicker];

    UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    [vc setView:view];
    [vc setContentSizeForViewInPopover:CGSizeMake(320, 260)];

    popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:vc];
    popover.delegate = self;



    [popover presentPopoverFromRect:myButton.bounds inView:myButton
           permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];


}
}
```

//Hope you got it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using this bit of code as per ibiren's suggestion from [UIDatePicker in UIPopover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341835/uidatepicker-in-uipopover) thread .

```
UIViewController* popoverContent = [[UIViewController alloc] init]; //ViewController

UIView *popoverView = [[UIView alloc] init];   //view
popoverView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

UIDatePicker *datePicker=[[UIDatePicker alloc]init];//Date picker
datePicker.frame=CGRectMake(0,44,320, 216);
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime;
[datePicker setMinuteInterval:5];
[datePicker setTag:10];
[datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(Result) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[popoverView addSubview:datePicker];

popoverContent.view = popoverView;
popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverContent];
popoverController.delegate=self;
[popoverContent release];

[popoverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 264) animated:NO];
[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:tempButton.frame inView:self.view     permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
//tempButton.frame where you need you can put that frame
```

Answer (score -1):

I know this answer came up late. But for anyone who would like to use this library…
The new version of ActionSheetDatePicker has the following properties:

```
NSDate *minimumDate;
NSInteger minuteInterval;
NSCalendar *calendar;
NSTimeZone *timeZone;
NSLocale *locale;
```

that allow you to modify the basic options of DatePicker as you want.