# UIDatePicker cut off in iPad

Tags: ipad, uidatepicker

I am creating a datepicker view and a toolbar for my iPad app, but I don't know how to set its boundaries. Right now I have this:

```
CGRect toolbarTargetFrame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height-216-44, 320, 44);
CGRect datePickerTargetFrame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height-216, 320, 216);
```

I think this was designed for the iPhone. Now, in my iPad, how do I set the bounds to make it fit across the entire screen, rather than being cut off? I also need to make this work in portrait and landscape. When I change the dimensions from 320 to 768, the picker is cut off in landscape mode... Thanks!

Comment: Please check my answer it may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341835/uidatepicker-in-uipopover/7343106#7343106